# Python: How to check the number of occurrences and top (n) values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to count up the number of occurrences of countries in a dataframe, below is the sample and also find the top 2 countries by occurrence.

```
         Date            Location
0  09/17/1908            Virginia
1  07/12/1912          New Jersey
2  08/06/1913              Canada
3  09/09/1913             England
4  10/17/1913             Germany
5  03/05/1915             Belgium
6  09/03/1915             Germany
7  07/28/1916            Bulgeria
8  09/24/1916             England
9  10/01/1916             England
```

Result value should be something like below:

```
Location  Count
England     3
Germany     2
```

Comment: Can you put what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have tried df.pivot_table() and df.groupby() but unfortunately I could not get the expected results from either of the functions. I am new to Python

Comment: @Soumyaansh did my answer work for you? If not, let me know what results you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
countCollection = df['collection'].value_counts()
```

`.value_counts()` will give you a count for the items from the collection named `collection` in a dataFrame.

Also, as you mentioned you're new to Python, to get the final value:

```
countCollection["a"]
```

will get the count value from the returned collection of counts, for the row with key "a".

Answer (score 0):

You may use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [size](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
counts = df.groupby('Location').size()
```

`counts` is of type `pandas.Series`. You may order it by

```
counts.sort_values(inplace=True)
```

---

Comparision to the answer of [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2483271/nick-bull):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# number of items in list
N = 1e4

# create a list uniformely samples characters
l = np.random.choice( list('abcd'), N )

# create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame( l, columns=['char'] )
```

using the ipython magic command [timeit](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) for `N=1e4`

```
In [1]: %timeit df.char.value_counts()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit df.groupby('char').size()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```

and `N=1e6`

```
In [1]: %timeit df.char.value_counts()
10 loops, best of 3: 64.2 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit df.groupby('char').size()
10 loops, best of 3: 73.2 ms per loop
```

For smaller DataFrames, `groupby` & `size` is faster than `value_counts`, but for larger DateFrames `value_counts` is faster than `groupby` & `size`